# How can I temoporary save data?

Tags: php

How can I store my data..  if you test the code...

> you must add one by one field

...  you will found the problem... it can't save the previous entry.. for example if i store **2** in one field.. when I enter next number and click **Add** it will delete previous...

```
<?php

$puzzle = array(0,0,6,4,3,2,0,5,3,0,0,6,4,4,0,0,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,2,6,4,0,0,1,3,0,1,3,4,5,0);
$solved = array(0,1,6,4,3,2,5,5,3,2,1,6,4,4,2,6,5,3,1,3,5,1,6,4,2,6,4,5,2,1,3,2,1,3,4,5,6);


for($i=1;$i<=36;$i  ){

    if($_POST['field'.$i]!=''){
        $puzzle[$i] = $_POST['field'.$i];
        break;
    }

}

class displayClass {
    public function display($field){
        $fieldNum=0;
        $puzzle=$field;
        GLOBAL $ids , $edited;
        $ids = array(0);
        echo "<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\"><table border = \"3\" ><tr>" ;

        for($i=1;$i<=36;$i  ){

            if($puzzle[$i]==0){
                $ids[] = $i;
                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"field".$i."\" maxlength=\"1\" size=\"1\"/></td>";  
            }  else {

                echo "<td>".$puzzle[$i]."</td>";

            }

            if($i%6==0){
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }

        echo "</td></table>";
    }
}


displayClass::display($puzzle) ;

echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add\" /></form>";


?>
```

[Code](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/03U6)

And also I am havig huge problem with formating questions..did the most of editing availabe..

Comment: For help with formatting your questions, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What do you mean by store my data? You mean the POST portion (the answer) that the user sends back?

Comment: well ... how can i save vars without using any files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should post your code here instead of linking to it. I don't know about most people, but it will probably dissuade them. Also, I'm having a hard time understanding what you want. I'm assuming what you are doing is overwritting a variable, and you wish to keep each value. Try using an array and setting it to a session variable like so.

```
<?php
session_start();
$var=array();
$var[]='info you want to keep.';
$var[]='more info you want to keep.';
$_SESSION['var']=$var;
?>
```

Comment: will session end if i move to the next php file?

Comment: Nope that's the beautiful thing about [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), they last so long as the session lasts. Which is something like 24 minutes by default. Google gc_maxlifetime if you wish to change it.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. I woud give you (Y) .. but have only 6 :/

Answer (score 0):

PHP variables are only kept while the page is being executed, at each request. For some more permanent storage you need to use files or a database. Look at [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for some simple file handling functions.

Alternatively, for small amounts of data, you can always use session variables. On every page where you want to access your data, you must put, before *anything*, a call to [`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). Then, you can use the `$_SESSION` array variable to set data.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['number']))
        $_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];

    if (isset($_SESSION['number']))
        echo $_SESSION['number'];
?>
```

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem without using database or any files..?

Comment: There is another way, I will update my answer.